# Writing function which distinguishes tail vs non-tail calls Scheme

Tags: scheme, tail-recursion

I'm trying to define a function which marks tail vs non-tail calls in an sexpr in scheme.
It would be defined as follows:

```
TCS ::= SYMBOL | NUMBER | IF | FUNCTION-CALL

IF ::= (if TCS TCS TCS)

FUNCTION-CALL ::= (TCS TCS...)
```

an example of an input/output would be:

```
(mark-tail-calls '(if (a (b c)) (e (f g) h) i) (j (k 7)))
=> (if (non-tail-call a (non-tail-call b c)) (non-tail-call e (non-tail-call f g) h) i) (tail-call j (non-tail-call k 7))
```

I understand the difference between a tail and non-tail call but I'm finidng it difficult to write the function considering I have little experience with scheme. Any help/point towards the right direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully a nudge to get you started:

You would usually do a case analysis on the structure of the input (and recurse).

Something along the lines of

```
(define (mark-tail-calls e)
    (cond ((null? e) '())
          ((symbol? e) e)
          ((number? e) e)
          ((if? e) (list 'íf ...)
          ((symbol? (car e)) ...)
          (#t ...))))
```

Where `if?` is defined as

```
(define (if? e)
  (and (pair? e)
        (equal? (car e) 'if)))
```